# How to display subcategories on category page?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree, category-page

I have used this code in view.phtml to display subcategories on category page

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName(), 'name') ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

but this is obviously displaying only the list of subcategories, I want image and same view as products on category page

**Desired Result**

[image]

**Getting this**

[image]

Favorite community please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a var dump of "$_subcat" inside the foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
    <?php var_dump($_subcat->getData()); die(); ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

You will display all the options available to use.

Comment: not working <br> array(7) { ["entity_id"]=> string(2) "46" ["name"]=> string(2) "LG" ["path"]=> string(12) "1/2/14/45/46" ["is_active"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_anchor"]=> string(1) "0" ["request_path"]=> string(36) "tv-and-home-theater/shop-by-brand/lg" ["id"]=> string(2) "46" }

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

$subcategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->getId());


foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory){ ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $subcategory->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $subcategory->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php }
```

Comment: not working :/ ...

Comment: Try using direct category ID instead:  $_category->getId()

Comment: still getting names only, i want images

Comment: For image use:    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'. $subcategory->getThumbnail(); ?>" alt=""  /> inside foreach loop

Comment: https://ibb.co/cpBFkk

Comment: images not showing

Comment: Back end category image uploaded right?

Comment: yes it is uploaded